# I receive a GET error when trying to serve html page with image using Node.js

Tags: html, css, node.js

I am new to Node.js and am unable to find a way to solve my issue. I have written a server using Node.js to serve a html webpage. The problem is that it wont display the images that are in the same folder. I am trying to serve my webpage as well as my images and css file. Any help would be appreciated.

Relevant code:

server:

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');

const PORT = 8080;

function handleRequest(request, response) {
    console.log(request.url);

    var bool = 0;

    var index = fs.readFileSync("index.html", {
        encoding: "utf-8"
        });

    if(request.url == "/")
    {
        bool = 1;
        response.end(index);
    }
    else if(request.url == "/index" || request.url == "/index.html")
    {
        bool = 1;
        response.end(index);
    }
    else if(bool == 0)
    {
        response.statusCode = 404; 
        response.end("Not Found");
    }

}

var server = http.createServer(handleRequest);

server.listen(PORT, function() {

console.log("Started server on http://localhost:%s", PORT)

});
```

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>My Personal Webpage</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="index-css.css"/>
</head>

<body>
<h1>Welcome!</h1>

<p>My paragraph.</p>

<img src="/family.jpg" alt="Family" style="width:342px;height:513px;">
<img src="/Another.jpeg" alt="Another" style="width:500px;height:500px;">

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend use `app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/FOLDER_NAME'))` in order to expose a folder to serve static files to the client. [Here is the documents](http://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html) about serving static files using express.

Edit: Here is a simple working example of serving a index.html using express

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

http.listen(3000, function(){
  console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```